# undefined controller in jasmine unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using karma via gulp-karma but getting the following error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'adminPagesCtrl' is not a function, got
>   undefined

Here is my spec file:

```
describe('adminPagesCtrl', function() {
    var $rootScope,
        controller;

    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.module('jhApp')
        .config(['$locationProvider',
            function($locationProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }]); 
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller;
        controller('adminPagesCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it('does a thing', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

I have checked the browser window that karma opens up and can see all the files loaded. Application is working fine. Not sure what else to try?

Comment: Why are you configuring a new module?  You shouldn't be configuring the module here.  Use only: `beforeEach(module('jhApp'));`  If the module is not loaded, then the controller will not be found (because it is registered inside the module).

Comment: I am not really too sure. But if I change 
angular.module('jhApp') to module('jhApp') I get an error saying:
Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
So If I remove config section
I get this error:
$location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!
So essentially I was just working through the errors and this is where I got to. Perhaps I need to fix the HTML5 error in a different way

Comment: Ok sorry. Looks like it was an incompatible version of angular-mocks with the version of angular. Upgraded angular-mocks to version 1.3.11 (angular is at 1.3.8) and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

This is now working:

```
describe('adminPagesCtrl', function() {
    var $rootScope,
        controller;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('jhApp')
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller;
        controller('adminPagesCtrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it('does a thing', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```